# Laravel: Use scope from related model to filter results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

**TLTR:**

How to get a Collection of from one model (Users) using scope method from another (UserSubscriber)? Models are in one-to-one relation.

**More about:**

I have two model related one-to-one:

Second model is only for some users that has extended, specific role (subscribers in this case)

**User model:**

```
class User extends \Sentinel\Models\User
{
    public function subscriber()
    {        
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserSubscriber', 'user_id');
    }       
}
```

**UserExtended model:**

```
class UserSubscriber extends Model
{  
    public function user()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }        

    public function scopeLangSubscribers($query, $langCode)
    {
        $query->where('languages_subscribed', 'LIKE', '%' . $langCode . '%');
    }    
}
```

**The goal is:**

***Get a Collection of Users using scope from UserSubscriber.***

(Without rewriting this scope method to User model.)

**Where I stuck:**

```
            $users = User::with(['subscriber' => function ($query) use ($lang) {
                $query->langSubscribers($lang);
            }])->get();
```

This returns me collection of all users with 'subscriber' set as null for some of them.

I've tried to filter them, but:

- It is probably not the best solution, because it iterates on entire big collection of users after retrieving all of them from DB

  ```
          $users = $users->filter(function($item) {
              return $item->subscriber != null;
          });
  ```

'subscriber' is not a column, so I can't do:

```
->whereNotNull('subscriber')
```

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:**

Alternatively, maybe there is a way to convert one collection (of subscribers) to another (users) afterretrieving this first, which can be done very aesy and clean:

```
$usersSubscribers = UserSubscriber::langSubscribers($lang)->get();
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to accomplish. Why does a user only have one subscriber? Surely a user should have many subscribers?

Comment: User "has one" subscriber means: This user is subscriber. Because not every user is a subscriber this additional information is stored in additional table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `whereHas` instead.

```
$users = User::with('subscriber')->whereHas('subscriber', function    ($query) use ($lang) {
    $query->langSubscribers($lang);
})->get();
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, thak You.
(Just fixed syntax)